# How do you call a function with multiple arguments inside same class method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, self, fractions

Below is the code of my Fraction class and I want to call the add class in my simplify class.

```
Class Fraction:
      
    def __add__(self, other: "Fraction") -> "Fraction": 
 
        n: int = (self.num * other.denom + self.denom * other.num) / self.simplify()
        d: int = (self.denom * other.denom) / self.simplify()
           
    def simplify(self) -> "Fraction":

    """ Function to find the gcd of the fraction and return the simplified fraction"""
        **a = self.__add__()**
        n1: Fraction = abs(self.num)
        n2: Fraction= abs(self.denom)
        gcd: int = 1

        k:int = 1
        while k <= n1 and k <= n2:
            if n1 % k == 0 and n2 % k == 0:
                gcd = k
            k += 1
        return gcd
```

The code in bold is erroneous, When I run the above code it throws "No value for argument "other", how do I call this method?

Comment: The same way you *call any method*, `self.method(argument)`

Comment: So can you suggest the change here? cause I tried it and get only errors.